# Limit for files opening

Tags: linux, bash, shell, limit

I am using the linux `ulimit` command to set some limits for opening files. If I am using `ulimit -n 4` this will open just 1 file.  If I am using `ulimit -n 5` this will open 2 files. So the formula will be `ulimit -n number of files+3`. The question is why is that difference of +3? What is that 3 reprezent? Maybe one for file one for executable file and one for...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each process has the first three open file descriptors: stdin, stdout, stderr